# Why can not get the elements from controlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

My behind code only one line as follow:

```
 Dim btn As Button = 
               CType(Me.simpleButton.Template.FindName("testbtn", simpleButton), Button)
```

Xaml file as follow:

```html
            <Button x:Name="simpleButton"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="5"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Command="{Binding SimpleOnCommand}"
                    Focusable="False">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="50">
                            <Border.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger 
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseRightButtonDown">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="rotateLine">
                                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="line11" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                                <DoubleAnimation By="360"
                                                                 Duration="0:0:1.5"
                                                                 RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled="True" RoutedEvent="MouseRightButtonUp">
                                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="rotateLine" />
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Border.Triggers>
                            <Viewbox x:Name="myView"
                                     Width="65"
                                     Height="65">
                                <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"
                                        Width="65"
                                        Height="65">
                                    <Canvas.CacheMode>
                                        <BitmapCache />
                                    </Canvas.CacheMode>
                                    <Button x:Name="testbtn"></Button>
                                    <Line x:Name="line1"
                                          RenderTransformOrigin="0,0"
                                          Stroke="Black"
                                          StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                                          StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                                          StrokeThickness="5"
                                          X1="{Binding X1}"
                                          X2="{Binding X2}"
                                          Y1="{Binding Y1}"
                                          Y2="{Binding Y2}">​
```

Use `Me.simpleButton.Template.FindName("name of elements", simpleButton)` can not get any elements(such as: "border","line1" etc.) from simpleButton control template. How should i do ?

Comment: I guess this is WPF?

Comment: I think you missed target type. set target TargetType=”{x:Type Button}”. Maybe it will work.

Comment: I have tried what you said, Its still not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild()` to locate the items.

Here's a C# example.

```
Border iconBorder = GetTemplateChild("PART_SearchIconBorder") as Border;
```

I think this would be the VB equivalent.

```
Dim btn As Button = 
               CType(Me.simpleButton.Template.GetTemplateChild("testbtn"), Button)
```

Comment: 'GetTemplateChild' is not a member  of  'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.  But I have used Me.GetTemplateChild("testbtn")  that dose not work.